# Set execution time for Script command to record terminal activity

Tags: linux, scripting, terminal, command, time

I want to set up a script to record terminal activity. After seeking out various sources, I came up to the idea of using Script command to perform this task. However, if I only use Script command, such as: `script - a /var/log/session/terminal.log` I have to manually type `exit`each time to stop the `script` command and get my record done. I try to use `timeout` to set an execution time for `script` command but the `script`command is actually killed by the signal and the recording file is left blank without any record.

In fact, I would like to set an execution time to record the terminal and continuously record the content into the file. Furthermore, If someone accidentally close the terminal, all the contents will be saved into a file before exiting. Could you please give me some advices on this problem?

Very Appreciated

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The `script` command opens a new shell.  Therefore it is exited like a normal shell.  Timed exit is not available since a shell the way you are using it (IIUC) is interactive.  It exits on "exit" or <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>d</kbd>.

If the input comes from a script, anything that will indicate end of text/transmission/input file will also make the shell exit.

One could work with signals to exit that shell but it would need a supervising script.  From the `bash` man page:

```
The shell exits by default upon receipt of a SIGHUP
```

So, if you could stard a shell and capture its process id this would stop it cleanly:

```
kill -HUP $SHELLPID
```

Here is a script that ought to do it:

```
#!/bin/bash

date=`date +%Y-%m-%d-%H%M`
logfile=`mktemp /tmp/terminal-log-${date}-XXX`

# call shell - try gnome-terminal if you prefer it
# gnome-terminal -- /usr/bin/script --quiet $logfile
xfce4-terminal --execute /usr/bin/script --quiet $logfile

ourpid=`readlink /proc/self`
scriptpid=`ps auxfw | grep -w $logfile | grep -v grep | awk '{print $2}'`
shellpid=`ps auxfw | grep -w --after=1 $logfile | grep -w --after=1 $scriptpid | tail -1 | awk '{print $2}'`

# feel free to delete this debug output
echo terminal started, script pid is $scriptpid, shell pid is $shellpid 

# sleep before stopping the shell - adjust time freely
sleep 10m

# flush script, just to be sure
kill -SIGUSR1 $scriptpid

# kill shell (cleanly, script and terminal should exit, too)
kill -HUP $shellpid
```

Comment: Do you mean the ```PID``` of the shell started by the ```script``` command, not the ```PID``` of the ```script``` command itself?

Comment: Yes that's the one. `script` -> `bash`. Send that `bash` a HUP and it will exit cleanly, then `script` will exit. Do you have a controlling process?  What is the parent of the `script` command and its parent? Some terminal?

Comment: I created a script by ```vi``` editor with the pathname as ```/bin/*.sh```. Then, I put the ```exec``` command in ```.bashrc``` so that the script is automatically executed at each start of the terminal. I notice that the shell is transferred from ```bash``` to ```csh``` after the script got started. Do you have any hint?

Comment: Just to be sure: Are we talking about `/usr/bin/script`? Otherwise I suppose details are missing, please add by editing your question - ideally add that shell script.  Also, it is usually better not to do the `exec` in `.bashrc` but instead do something like `gnome-terminal --command /bin/myterm.sh` (modify starter button) otherwise you cannot easily control when it is started and when not (to debug).

Comment: yes, it is exactly ```/usr/bin/script``` used to record terminal session not the shell script. Sorry for any confusion about my comment.

Comment: OK, @Hunglk I added a script which does the job for me, see whether it does for you. If so feel free to upvote :)